# is it possible to access internal hosts from ssh terminal using ssh tunnel from windows directly?

Tags: networking, ssh, putty

I have a Ubuntu server that I do web development on at work. At work I use a Windows PC but I am on the internal network so I can Putty into the server to change code. I access the pages it serves from Windows.

From home on my Windows 8.1 PC I can use Putty to SSH into the Gateway Server and from the commnad terminal SSH again to get to my dev server. However I cannot open webpages I am working on from my Windows PC.

My boss helped me set up an SSH tunnel to remote into my work computer. But I don't have remote user account access and will need to go to work to fix that. In the mean time I would like to learn more about ssh tunneling and wondering if/how to direct my windows machine to use the SSH tunnel to resolve the IP address so I can view the webpages from my test server on it.

Also my ssh tunnel uses a destination IP of another server which I guess is the windows server 
The port forwards and connects to the Windows Remote server correctly but I cannot connect to it from my ssh terminal I open which is the one that specifies the tunnel in the first place! How does that even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I could set up another SSH tunnel to my dev server and access the web pages through my local machine that way.

The reason I couldn't SSH into the Windows Remote Server was because it doesn't have an SSH server available only remote desktop.